# Unable to keep a checkbox punched

Tags: jquery

I have a table in which one checkbox comes already checked when page loads. I want that respondent is unable to change that punch. So i am trying that if someone clicks on that checkbox, that checkbox gets checked again automatically however this code is not working. Below is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr td').each(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').change(function(){
      $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not just disable the checkbox? Probably a good idea to signal to the user that this checkbox should stay checked, instead of frustrating them by re-checking it whenever it is unchecked..? Just a suggestion.

Comment: Why not disable the checkbox?

Comment: Why waste space presenting an option that the user can't change?

Comment: set the attribute/property disabled="disabled" in when declaring your checkbox like so: `<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" disabled="disabled">`

Comment: @TimBüthe Because my question is mandatory and if a respondent does not select any other checkbox and tries to move further, my tool gives respondent an error because disabled checkbox is no longer working as a checkbox for tool and respondent has not answered anything. and when page loads, auto punch also disappear because that is in previous script.

Comment: @DavidThomas I am working on a tool and I need to show the selected answer option. Even when I am trying to throw an alert if user removes check..alert is coming twice, not sure why..

Comment: render it as disabled fulfils all needs

Comment: In which case you have the `readonly` attribute (which will allow the element to be successful), or `disabled` (which makes the element unsuccessful). Which you choose depends on whether you want to submit that form-element to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps do as the others suggest and `disable` altogether.  Alternatively if you want your code to work, you are using the wrong selector in the second part as `this` refers to the checkbox selected by the previous selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr td').each(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').change(function(){
      $(this).prop('checked',true); // <-- Here `this` means the checkbox already.
      });
  });
});
```